# Same array binded to two SwiftUI Views hangs-up App when object deleted

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I try to build an app in MacOS SwiftUI, where two different subviews of main contentView shows different parts of `Axis` element:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var document: GlyphDesignerDocument
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            #warning("if AxesSlidersView is not commented, and Axis will be deleted — program explodes")
            AxesSlidersView(axes: $document.axes)
            AxesView(axes: $document.axes,
                     addRows: {document.axes.insert(Axis("z", bounds: 0...1000), at: $0)},
                     removeRows: {document.axes.remove(at: $0)},
                     addAxis: {document.axes.append(Axis("z", bounds: 0...1000))})     
        }
    }
```

Subviews works great, everything updates in both ways, but application hangs-up when `AxisView` will delete one `Axis` from `axes` array.

All code is available at https://github.com/typoland/GlyphDesignerTest
AxesView looks like this:

```
struct AxesView : View {
    @Binding var axes: [Axis]
    @State var selected: Int? = nil
    var addRows: (_ at:Int) -> Void
    var removeRows: (_ at: Int) -> Void
    var addAxis: () -> Void
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            .... Shows Axes
        }
    }
}

struct AxisView: View {
    
    @Binding var axis: Axis
    var insert: () -> Void
    var delete: () -> Void
    @Binding var selected: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            .... Shows one Axis
        }
    }
}
struct AxesSlidersView: View {
    @Binding var axes: [Axis]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            .... Shows Axes
        }
    }
}
```

Is it SwiftUI problem? How to deal with this?

Github version, whole small app looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of app, full code at gitHub]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recall there were problems with direct binding with `onDelete`. Try with proxy binding in `AxesSlidersView` as below:

```
Slider(value: Binding(get: { axes[index].at }, set: {axes[index].at = $0}), in: axes[index].bounds)
    .frame(idealWidth: metrics.frame(in: .global).width*0.6)
```

Comment: I know, this is not place to say „Thank You” but „Thank You”. At least one week I tried to solve this problem.

Comment: But now changes made on .at in SlidersView are not reflected in AxesView...

Comment: When I made proxy in upper view `Binding(get: {axes[index]}, set:{axes[index] = $0})` it started to work as should. Could you edit your answer, please?